# JSON Array Name Change in Python

Tags: python, json, list

I need to change the name of the JSON array at the very beginning of this JSON to "data" in Python. Right now I am simply receiving and printing out the JSON like this:

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('select * from stuff')
return json.dumps(c.fetchall())
```

Here is the JSON:

```
[
      {
           status: "F",
           id_num: "001",
      },
      {
           status: "T",
           id_num: "002",
      },
      {
           status: "T",
           id_num: "003",
      }
]
```

What do I need to do to insert `"data":` right before the first square bracket indicating the array?

Comment: You are not changing a name. You are putting this list inside another dictionary.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? It won't be a valid json afterwards. If you do that you would need `{ 'data': your array }`. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the list in a new dictionary:

```
return json.dumps({'data': c.fetchall()})
```

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that. That solved the problem. Thanks for the help.